# Springboot 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: java, angular, mongodb, docker, spring-boot

I apologize beforehand for the long write up!

BACKGROUND:

The service I am working on has a frontend of angular 7, backend of springboot 2.0.0.RELEASE, and a database layer of MongoDB (latest docker version). All 3 layers of the application are running in their own docker container on the same RHEL machine, but they are all on the same docker network.

The angular app is being statically hosted through an nginx container and springboot is running as a jar with that command 'java -jar app.jar'. I have not altered and Docker fields except the ports, so all other options for docker are the default.

PROBLEM:

When I launch all three containers and try to run protractor e2e tests against them I will sporadically receive a 503 Service Unavailable from the backend. I have a suite of 12 tests with all tests running sequentially. I wait till all of the containers are fully up before executing the tests and it will randomly fail on any one of the 12 tests. After a test fails I will run through the test steps manually and try to replicate, but it always passes. When I run the backend as gradle springboot in a docker container I do not experience any issues. So the issue is only when I try to run the automated tests against the dockerized jar.

I have increased the logging from DEBUG to TRACE on the spring web logs and everything checks out to be ok.

I believe this to be a memory problem. Could it be a java heap issue with running the java jar or an overload of api calls to the backend or to the database? Could this be related to allocating to much memory to the mongo and nginx containsers.

Any information or alternative hypothesis's to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Bruh, angular 7 doesn't exist yet. You're in the future

Answer (score 0):

did you actually analyse the memory usage? if it is a memory issue, this might help:

mongo is known to be very aggressive allocating memory, especially the wired tiger storage engine just eats memory. also, in a container, it is not aware of anyone else using memory. you might want to tell it to be less greedy:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#memory-use

also, it is a good idea to limit each container's resources (especially if they're competing on the same machine):

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory

hope this helps